# How to increase page loading speed in PHP?

Tags: php, streaming

I am developping a website for watching movies online using php and I want to know how to increase page load time for pages.

Because my pages contain a lot of content I do not know how I can get more speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an old joke: A man goes to his doctor. The doctor gives him a thorough checkup, runs tests, and so on. The doctor then says, "You know, the best thing for your health would be if you exercised more, ate better, lost weight, and quit smoking and drinking to excess." The man replies, "What would the second best thing be?"

There's no magic secret, other than caching the PHP scripts, designing the PHP scripts to be efficient, using appropriate hardware and software, and measuring to see if you got it right or screwed up.